# How can I grep and sort text files using Perl?

Tags: perl, text, grep

I have a simple log file which is very messy and I need it to be neat. The file contains log headers, but they are all jumbled up together. Therefore I need to sort the log files according to the log headers. There are no static number of lines - that means that there is no fixed number of lines for the each header of the text file. And I am using perl grep to sort out the headers.

The Log files goes something like this:

```
Car LogFile Header
<text>
<text>
<text>
Car LogFile Header
<text>
Car LogFile Header
<and so forth>
```

I have done up/searched a simple algorithm but it does not seem to be working. Can someone please guide me? Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#use 5.010; # must be present to import the new 5.10 functions, notice 
#that it is 5.010 not 5.10


my $srce = "./root/Desktop/logs/Default.log";
my $string1 = "Car LogFile Header";
open(FH, $srce);
my @buf = <FH>;
close(FH);
my @lines = grep (/$string1/, @buffer);
```

After executing the code, there is no result shown at the terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, if you want to show results, you have to output something.

Comment: You use `@buf` first but then refer to it as `@buffer`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
 my $srce = "./root/Desktop/logs/Default.log";
 my $string1 = "Car LogFile Header";

 open my $fh, '<',  $srce or die "Could not open $srce: $!";

 my @lines = sort grep /\Q$string1/, <$fh>;
 print @lines;
```

Make sure you have the right file path and that the file has lines that match your test pattern.

It seems like you are missing a lot of very basic concepts and maybe cutting and paste code you see elsewhere. If you're just starting out, pick up a Perl tutorial such as [Learning Perl](http://www.learning-perl.com). There are other books and references listed in [perlfaq2](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq2.html).

Comment: I don't get why is the "my" at $fh cause the system's giving this error now "Global symbol "$scre" requires explicit package name" as the $srce should have no problem.

Comment: @JavaNoob: because "$scre" is not spelled the same as "$srce".

Comment: Oops.....Didnt notice that thanks.. But It seems that the codes only print out the header and not the paragraph. I guess must be the question being asked wrong. Anyway its the right answer.

Comment: Provide a short sample file, then show us exactly what you want the output to be. Don't accept this answer if it's not giving you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Always use:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

This would have told you that `@buffer` is not defined.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $srce = "./root/Desktop/logs/Default.log";
my $string1 = "Car LogFile Header";
open(my $FH, $srce) or die "Failed to open file $srce ($!)";
my @buf = <$FH>;
close($FH);
my @lines = grep (/$string1/, @buf);
print @lines;
```

Perl is tricky for experts, so experts use the warnings it provides to protect them from making mistakes.  Beginners need to use the warnings so they don't make mistakes they don't even know they can make.

(Because you didn't get a chance to `chomp` the input lines, you still have newlines at the end so the `print` prints the headings one per line.)

Comment: error appears "readline() on closed filehandle $FH at ./rgex.pl line 9.". Any thoughts on that?

Comment: If you'd checked the return value of the open(), you'd catch that sort of thing.

Comment: What version of Perl are you using?  It worked OK for me, cut'n'paste from the answer, with 5.13.4, 5.10.1, 5.8.8.  It failed with 5.6.2 - couldn't locate strict, which is slightly puzzling...OTOH, it was a PowerPC build of Perl running on my (Intel) Mac running Snow Leopard (10.6.4) and I've not used it in a long time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think grep is what you want really.
As you pointed out in brian's answer, the grep will only give you the headers and not the subsequent lines.

I think you need an array where each element is the header and the subsequent lines up to the next header.

Something like: -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $srce = "./default.log";
my $string1 = "Car LogFile Header";
my @logs;
my $log_entry;
open(my $FH, $srce) or die "Failed to open file $srce ($!)";

my $found = 0;
while(my $buf = <$FH>)
{
    if($buf =~ /$string1/)
    {
        if($found)
        {
            push @logs, $log_entry;
        }

        $found = 1;
        $log_entry = $buf;
    }
    else
    {
        $log_entry = $log_entry . $buf; 
    }
}

if($found)
{
    push @logs, $log_entry;
}

close($FH);

print sort @logs;
```

i think it's what is being asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Perl `grep` is not same as Unix `grep` command in that it does not print anything on the screen.

The general syntax is: `grep Expr, LIST`

Evaluates `Expr` for each element of `LIST` and returns a list consisting of those elements for which the expression evaluated to `true`.

In your case all the `@buffer` elements which have the vale of `$string1` will be returned.

You can then print the `@buffer` array to actually see them.

Comment: He means you can't just define an array and expect a screen output from it. To get a screen output you have to `print` the array.

Answer (score 0):

You just stored everything in an array instead of printing it out. It's also not necessary to keep the whole file in memory. You can read and print the match results line by line, like this:

```
my $srce = "./root/Desktop/logs/Default.log";
my $string1 = "Car LogFile Header";
open(FH, $srce);
while(my $line = <FH>) { 
  if($line =~ m/$string1/) {
    print $line;
  }
}
close FH;
```

Comment: Still no result shown. It just skips to a blank line in the terminal.

Comment: No, try it with the logfile text you gave above. It will output all the "Car Logfile Header" lines it can find.

Answer (score -1):

Hello I found a way to extract links from html file

## !/usr/bin/perl -w

```
  2 
  3 # Links graber 1.0
  2 
  3 # Links graber 1.0
  4 #Author : peacengell
  5 #28.02.13
  6 
  7 ####
  8 
  9 my $file_links = "links.txt";
 10 my @line;
 11 my $line;
 12 
 13 
 14 open( FILE, $file_links ) or die "Can't find File";
 15 
 16 while (<FILE>) {
 17 chomp;
 18 $line = $_ ;
 19 
 20 @word = split (/\s+/, $line);
 21 @word  = grep(/href/, @word);
 22 foreach  $x (@word) {
 23 
 24 if ( $x =~ m /ul.to/ ){
 25 $x=~ s/href="//g;
 26 $x=~s/"//g;
 27 print  "$x \n";
 28 
 29                         
 30                         }
 31                 
 32                 }
 33         
 34         }
```

you can use it and modify it please let me know if you modify it.