# How can I grep a paragraph in Perl?

Tags: perl, grep, paragraph

I have a log file which needs to be properly formatted into a readable format. However the text file has no static number of lines or fixed primary values and has random number of spaces but has only a log file header which can be used to pin point the start and end of each time the application logs.

An Example of the log file:

```
Log File header
<text>
<text>
Log File header
<text>
```

After the script has been formatted it should look something like this:

```
Log File header
<text>
<text>

<space>

Log File header
<text>
<text>
```

Therefore I need some advice on greping out an entire paragraph everytime the Perl Script detects a "Log File header".

Here is the grep perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#use 5.010; # must be present to import the new 5.10 functions, notice 
#that it is 5.010 not 5.10

my $file = "/root/Desktop/Logfiles.log";
open LOG, $file or die "The file $file has the error of:\n =>  $!";

@lines = <LOG>;
close (LOG);

@array = grep(/Log File header/, @lines);

print @array;
```

Can someone please give some advice on the codes? Thanks.

Comment: Don't hardcode filenames into your scripts, supply them as arguments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I grep and sort text files using Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783909/how-can-i-grep-and-sort-text-files-using-perl)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I read paragraphs at a time with Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809469/how-do-i-read-paragraphs-at-a-time-with-perl)

Comment: I tried to supply them as arguments but as this script is for Logs I don't think that I have a dynamic object to filter through the regular expression as I need to only filter the Headers. Thanks for the extra advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just want vertical space in between your log file sections?

There are a few approaches, particularly because you know the header will be on a completely separate line. In all the following examples assume that `@lines` has already been populated from your input file.

So first technique: insert spaces before header:

```
foreach my $line ( @lines ) {
    if ( $line =~ m/Log File header/ ) {
        print( "\n\n\n" ); # or whatever you want <space> to be
    }

    print( $line );
}
```

The next technique is to use a regular expression to search/replace blocks of text:

```
my $space = "\n\n\n"; # or whatever you want <space> to be
my $everything = join( "", @lines );
$everything =~ s/(Log File header.*?)(?=Log File header)/$1$space/sg;
print( $everything );
```

Some explanation about the regexp. The `(?=` means "look-ahead" which will match but not form part of the expression to be replaced. The `/sg` modifiers mean `s`-treat newlines as ordinary whitespace and `g`-do a global search-and-replace. The `.*?` means select anything, but as little as possible to satisfy the expression (non-greedy), which is extremely important in this application.

*update*: edited first technique in which I'd failed to explicitly specify which variable to do the match upon.

Comment: Thanks mate! The first technique only seems to print the entire log with no changes but the second technique works just fine! Thanks again mate!

Comment: Oh my mistake, I will edit the first answer, I didn't explicitly specify which variable to match on. You should find the first one works now.

Comment: The first code still doesn't work as it just reprints the entire log again. Mind if I ask why do you need the code "my $everything = join( "", @lines );"for the second working code? How does it contribute to the regular expression? Does it have something to do with the /s? Thanks again mate!

Comment: Please look at `perldoc -f join` for documentation on the join function. If you're unsure of the difference between scalars and arrays it's time to learn the basics of Perl.